# Drivers for MacBook Pro 2019 not working every time (Ubuntu)

Tags: drivers, macbook, macbook-pro

I'm new here and to Ubuntu. I have a MacBook Pro 2019 13-inch (with T2) and I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (using dual boot with MacOS and Ubuntu).

I did my best to install all the drivers needed and everything has worked at least once, the problem is that it's only sometimes. Most times it works completely but sometimes I turn my machine and the keyboard, trackpad, touch bar, camera, aux port, or mic don't work. It feels like it's random,and I am not sure what's causing this. Any idea why this would happen? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/ if you already haven't.

Comment: I have, that's where I got most of my information from and it worked great compared to other sources. Some drivers work more than others (e.g. keyboard and trackpad fail once every 10 boots while touchbar fails almost every single time).